# Raspberry Pi 3 OpenWrt

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi3, openwrt

I have a trouble build OpenWrt with SD card.

I download the source, git://github.openwrt.org/openwrt.git and run "make menuconfig", set target "brcm27xx", "brcm2710", "Raspberry Pi 3 Model B".

And finish the configuration, build success.

Using "sudo dd if=openwrt....img of=/dev/sdb bs=2M", I create SD card.

When I boot Raspberry Pi 3 with creating SD card, the Kernel message with error.

run "mount"

/dev/root/ type ext4 ro(read-only) file system.

What is the problem!! Because of this I can not do anything...

Please Help me...

Comment: What is the Kernel error message?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using dd for a while now and it is both very powerful and very unforgiving, in the sense that your console will suggest the writing of the image is concluded but in actuality it has not. My images constantly failed for much the same reason as yours so now use my alternative command line, see below....

sudo dd if=openwrt....img of=/dev/sdb bs=2M

Here is my suggestion

sudo dd if=openwrt....img of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=sync,notrunc status=progress; sudo sync

the last command may be unnecessary as sync is defined within dd command line. remember all of the above is one a line command not two wrap is ok I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost a year old and people might come across this in the future.

To run OpenWRT/LEDE on Raspberry Pi, you need to flash an image on a microSD. You may download the images through this link(Just search for the particular RPi Model): https://openwrt.org/toh/views/toh_fwdownload

Then from personal experience, I use Etcher to flash the image on the microSD. You may download it through this link: https://etcher.io/

Hope this helps someone out there. :)